# android generate randomly unique color code

Tags: android, algorithm, random

I want to generate random,unique color code. Is there any algorithm ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Random color = new Random();

Color randomColor = new Color(color.nextInt(256),color.nextInt(256),color.nextInt(256));
```

Ofcouse pedantically speaking, not assured to be random ;)

Comment: I have used java.awt.color. For android you could do the same with paint object. Paint p = new Paint(color.nextInt(256),color.nextInt(256),color.nextInt(256),color.nextInt(256)). Ofcourse I will probably set alpha to be opaque all the time.

Comment: Answer doesn't fit tag _Android_